# $ABCD$ is a trapezium with $CD \parallel AB$ and $CD$ is a tangent to the circle.

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a trapezium with $CD \parallel AB$ and $CD$ is a tangent to the circle, as shown in the figure. $AB$ is a diameter of the circle. $E$ & $F$ are mid points of $AD$ & $BC$ respectively. Find the angle $ABC$.

[image: Figure at below link]

Comment: At the moment $E$ and $F$ are not telling us anything, and $\angle ABC$ could be basically anything, as $C$ could be placed almost anywhere along that line. Are they $E$ and $F$ both the midpoints of their respective sides and where those sides intersect the circle?

Comment: just given the midpoints of respective sides as per question.

Comment: Then we can't answer the problem. [Here is an image of two figures, both fulfilling your criteria](https://i.imgur.com/8GMh7nx.png). I haven't marked off $E$ and $F$ on them, but that doesn't matter. Can you see how $\angle ABC$ cannot be solved for the way you've described the trapezium? I would be willing to bet money that the _intent_ was to have $E$ and $F$ be where the circle intersected the sides, regardless of whether it has actually been written here.

Comment: if you assume the points E and F be where the circle intersected the sides, in that case the measure of ABC ?? the answer provided is 75 degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join O(the center) and P(the point of contact). Let EF cut OP at M. Then, $\angle PFM = \angle OFM$ by congruent triangles.

[image]

Note that (1) $\angle PFA = \angle PBA = 45^0$; and (2) $\angle BAF = \angle OFA = \angle AFE$. Each one of them $= ...= 15^0$

Comment: thanks mate for approach. Got angle ABC = 75 degree

Comment: @Mbisht Good! Glad to see that helps.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $H$ is the projection of $F$ on $AB$, then $FH$ is half radius.